# How to get spark executor longs using customSparkLister

Tags: scala, apache-spark, logging

I have an spark 2.4.4 with scala 2.11.10 application running in yarn cluster. For looking into the insights of an application, i wrote

```
lass CustomListener extends SparkListener with Logging{
  override def onJobStart(jobEnd: SparkListenerJobStart): Unit = {
    logInfo(s"---------------------------  Job started with ID = ${ jobEnd.jobId}  ---------------------------")
    logInfo(s"Number of Stages in Job ${jobEnd.jobId}: ${jobEnd.stageInfos.length}")
  }

  override def onStageCompleted(stageCompleted: SparkListenerStageCompleted): Unit = {
    println(stageCompleted.stageInfo.accumulables.mkString(", "))
    val runningTime = ((stageCompleted.stageInfo.completionTime match {
      case Some(completionTime) => completionTime
      case None => 0 // Handle the case when completionTime is not available
    })
      - (stageCompleted.stageInfo.submissionTime match {
      case Some(completionTime) => completionTime
      case None => 0 // Handle the case when completionTime is not available
    }))
    logInfo(s" Stage ${stageCompleted.stageInfo.stageId } takes ${millisToHumanReadableTime(runningTime)} ms to complete ${stageCompleted.stageInfo.numTasks} task(s)")
  }
  override def onTaskEnd(taskEnd: SparkListenerTaskEnd): Unit = {
    val taskInfo = taskEnd.taskInfo
    val taskId = taskInfo.taskId
    val executorId = taskInfo.executorId
    val host = taskInfo.host
    val duration = taskInfo.duration

    logInfo(s"Task $taskId on Executor: $executorId, Host: $host run for ${millisToHumanReadableTime(duration)} ms")
  }
```

The logs in the driver code is logging to driver sysout logs, but i want the logs in application code also in driver sysout logs.

Could you please tell me how to forward the logs in the executor to driver. It was appreciable if the approach uses sparkListener.